# Using API to fetch data from one site to display on another

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I have a site on Wordpress where I am trying to find the best way to create a dropdown which displays data from a  custom taxonomy to eventually integrate it into a different site (also on Wordpress).

Where I have go to is trying to obtain the correct Routes/URL's to fetch this information.

I have a Post type called `listings` which has a taxonomy called `listing_area`  which has different areas where posts are associated, e.g. Wales, East Anglia.

I have got so far that I have decided to use the Plugin WP-API (whether this is the right thing I don't know, I am aware that Wordpress now had an API in it's new update). I have managed to get this URL working and pulling in the terms of `listing_area` - `http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/taxonomies/listing_area/terms/174`

This is the test page I have going which is linking to these URL's in turn -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/test/
```

I have no idea if I'm doing the right thing here and I have very basic knowledge on it and would hugely appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're going on the right path, but I suggest to work straight with the fresh Wordpress REST API if you can upgrade your websites to 4.4. Otherwise you can still use your REST plugin as it is pretty much the same. I'll try to explain how to go through what you want to achieve (navigate through terms of a distant Wordpress website and display posts related to this terms).

---

### Get the terms from the other WP

Using the new WP REST API, here is a small function that you can use to get your taxonomy terms:

```
public function getDistantTerms($taxonomy) {
    $response = wp_remote_get('http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/' . $taxonomy);
    if(is_wp_error($response)) {
        return array();
    }
    return json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
}
```

Here I make use of [`wp_remote_get`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) function to get the JSON return from the REST function [`terms`](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/terms/) by passing it as parameter the taxonomy slug (ex:`listing_area`) - [here is a demo](http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/category) of what it returns. Add this function to your *functions.php* then use it in your template to build up your select:

```
<select name="term_select">
  <option value="">Please choose a term</option>
  <?php foreach(getDistantTerms('listing_area') as $term): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

It seems that's pretty much what you actually got.

---

### Link your select to a custom template

So the next step is to redirect to a page that list the posts of the term you choose. First we handle the redirection in JS:

```
$('select[name="term_select"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() != "") {
    window.location = "/show-post-term/" + $(this).val();
  }
});
```

We add a little rewrite rule to redirect this url (change it to whatever you want) to a template we'll name *distant-posts.php* (all of this take place in your theme *functions.php*):

**1. Add the rewrite rule**

```
add_action('init', 'distantposts_rewrite_rules');
function distantposts_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule('show-post-term/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?term_slug=$matches[1]&distant_post=true', 'top');
}
```

**2. Add two query vars**

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'distantposts_query_vars' );
function distantposts_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'term_slug';
    $vars[] = 'distant_post';
    return $vars;
}
```

**3. Redirect to the template if query vars are set**

```
add_filter('template_include', 'yourpluginname_blah_template_include', 1, 1); 
function yourpluginname_blah_template_include($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    $distant_post = $wp_query->query_vars['distant_post'];
    $term_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['term_slug'];
    if($distant_post && $term_slug) {
        $tpl = locate_template(array('distant-posts.php'));
        if(!empty($tpl)) {
            return $tpl;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

So in short what we're doing here: we add a rule that handle the `/show-post-term/term-slug` URL by redirecting it to index with two query vars: one that tell we're in a "distant posts" mode and one that carry the term slug. Then we declare those query vars to Wordpress, and use them to change the template that Worpdress should display if they're set.

---

### List the distants posts from the taxonomy term

Back to the REST API. We use the GET REST function [`posts`](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) by passing it as GET parameters the taxonomy name as key, and the term slug as value. [Here is a demo](http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?category=ab-iusto) of what kind of return you get.

**An important note before going further:** after you updated to WP 4.4, you need to change your taxonomy declaration in order to make this work. You need to add to your declaration the parameter `show_in_rest` set to `true`, and set `query_var` to `true`.

So we add this little function to *functions.php* to retrieve the posts from the template:

```
public function getDistantPosts($taxonomy, $term) {
    $response = wp_remote_get('http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?' . $taxonomy . '=' . $term);
    if(is_wp_error($response)) {
        return array();
    }
    return json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
}
```

And then in your template, you call it this way:

```
global $wp_query;
$posts = getDistantPosts('listing_area', $wp_query->query_vars['term_slug']);
```

Then use the `$posts` array to display your posts (it contain regular post objects).

---

### Going further

A few things that you may want to do now that you have the context established:

- **Add cache to the REST return**

  In order to avoid to overload your main website server, you should really consider caching your REST calls results. I will not detail this here as there is some work to do on it, but a good start could be [this script](https://github.com/Shelob9/jp-rest-cache).
- **Add pagination to your distant posts template**

  If you have a lot of posts associated to your terms, you might want to add a pagination. You can change a bit the distant posts REST function to add the `page` parameter for this - [see the documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/).
- **Add a "single page" for your distant posts**

  You might want to have individual pages for your distant posts on your main website, as the text might be too long for the list mode. You can start on the *distant-posts.php* code and add a `post_id` query var, then use the REST `posts` function to get your post like this : `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<post_id>`

To understand the basics of the WP REST API I strongly suggest you to visit the [wp-api.org](http://v2.wp-api.org/) website. There is a [pretty good article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-wordpress-rest-api/) on the REST API on wpmudev.org that you can read too. If you need to learn about the REST basics, I suggest you to read [the Wikipedia post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) about it.

Hope you'll manage to get through this, have fun!

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I will have a go!

Comment: @vard we have 2 different php sites with different databases for each site.

1st site is e-commerce shopping site, so that we saved some order related information in "order table".

we dont copy "order table" from 1st site to 2nd site.

we need to display those order information in 2nd site dashboard using APIs.

is this possible ?

Comment: @PhpBeginner It depends a lot of the context, but if your e-commerce website is a Woocommerce one, you can make use of the [Woocommerce native REST API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/). It have a [orders method](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders) that you can use to list all orders from the distant website. If you have trouble with this I suggest to post a new question and ping me about it, I'll take a look.

Comment: @vard do you prefer displaying `order information using API` or is it better to `copy "orders table" from 1st site to 2nd site and than display in dashboard using 2nd site database` ?

Comment: @PhpBeginner I don't know the context of both of your website and why you want to achieve this, but if you need it to be synced the API is the way to go. Though if you just want a snapshot of the orders at a given time, sure you can just copy the orders table - but you will need to copy users too, and users meta too, and products too... etc. It seems [there is a plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/) which is doing this, but I never tested it and can't tell if it actually works.

Comment: @vard thanks for link, but we planning for connecting `magento + php`.....

Answer (score 0):

I found this this url got me the results I needed -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=channel
```

my post type being `listings` and the slug of my term `channel`